# How do modify pandas index using regex and then compare it to the index of another dataframe?

Tags: regex, pandas

I want to rename the indices of my pandas dataframe by retaining only the substring before the third hyphen. My code doesn't modify the indices. Why?

```
import re

for i in meth_450.index:
    re.sub(r"^[^-]*-[^-]*:[^-]*", "", i)
```

`meth_450.index`

```
Index(['TCGA-06-0125-01A-01D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0125-02A-11D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0152-01A-02D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0152-02A-01D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0171-01A-02D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0171-02A-11D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0190-01A-01D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0190-02A-01D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0210-01A-01D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0210-02A-01D-2004-05'],
      dtype='object', length=155)
```

Desired output:

```
TCGA-06-0125, TCGA-06-0125,
TCGA-06-0152, TCGA-06-0152,
TCGA-06-0171, TCGA-06-0171,
TCGA-06-0190, TCGA-06-0190,
TCGA-06-0210, TCGA-06-0210
```

Ultimately, I want to match this dataframe to another dataframe:

```
clin = clin[clin.index.isin(meth_450.index)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
index = pd.Index(['TCGA-06-0125-01A-01D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0125-02A-11D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0152-01A-02D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0152-02A-01D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0171-01A-02D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0171-02A-11D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0190-01A-01D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0190-02A-01D-2004-05',
       'TCGA-06-0210-01A-01D-A45W-05', 'TCGA-06-0210-02A-01D-2004-05']
)

# You can extract by character count if your index is always consistent
index.str[:12]

# if you want to use regex: use .+? for non-greedy match
index.str.extract("^(.+?-.+?-.+?)-")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re

for i in meth_450.index:
    re.sub(r"^\w*[-]\w*[-]\w*", "", i)
```

you have an error in your regex, it should be `^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*` not `^[^-]*-[^-]*:[^-]*`

Answer (score 0):

**Don't forget to assign back after substitution** whatever method you use:

```
meth_450.index = meth_450.index.str.extract(r'^([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)', expand=False)
print(meth_450.index)

# Output
Index(['TCGA-06-0125', 'TCGA-06-0125', 'TCGA-06-0152', 'TCGA-06-0152',
       'TCGA-06-0171', 'TCGA-06-0171', 'TCGA-06-0190', 'TCGA-06-0190',
       'TCGA-06-0210', 'TCGA-06-0210'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `re.sub(r"-\w{3}-\w{3}-\w{4}-\d\d", "", i)`

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining how your pattern solves the problem presented in the question. Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality on Stack Overflow.